# recyclerView не отображает данные

Tags: recyclerview, список

Помогите, пожалуйста, recyclerView не отображает данные, хотя данные приходят, смотрел через лог. В условие вывода тоже заходит.

public static boolean isEmpty = false;

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "--->TaskAdapter";

    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public TaskAdapter(long from, long to) {
        Task.loadTasks(null, from, to);
        ListOfTaskFragment.this.setInfo(Task.getTasks().size());
        if(Task.getTasks().size() == 0)
            this.tasks = null;
        else
            this.tasks = Task.getTasks();
    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        if(tasks == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_task_empty, parent, false);
            //return new TaskViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, 0);
        }
        else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false);
            //return new TaskViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        return new TaskViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(tasks == null) {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        else {
            isEmpty = false;
            if(tasks.get(position).isLate(new Date().getTime())) {
                holder.title.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.deleted));
            }
            else {
                holder.title.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
            holder.title.setText(tasks.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.manager.setText(tasks.get(position).getManagerFIO());
            holder.end_date.setText(TimeFormatter.sdf1C.format(tasks.get(position).getDateDue()));
            holder.count_products.setText("продуктов: " + Task.getTask(position).getProducts().size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(tasks == null)
            return 1;
        else
            return tasks.size();
    }
}



class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public TextView manager;
    public TextView count_products;
    public TextView end_date;
    public RelativeLayout rl;

    public Button button;

    public TaskViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_title);
        manager = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_manager);
        count_products = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_products);
        end_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_date);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_tasks_rl);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isEmpty == false) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskEditActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("task_position", getAdapterPosition());
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Client.loadClients();
                    if (Client.getClients().size() > 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskEditActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Нет данных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TaskViewHolder(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_task_empty, parent, false));

        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emptyButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Client.loadClients();
                if(Client.getClients().size() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskEditActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Нет данных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TaskViewHolder(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false));

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_title);
        title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        manager = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_manager);
        count_products = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_products);
        end_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_task_date);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_tasks_rl);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isEmpty == false) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskEditActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("task_position", getAdapterPosition());
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Client.loadClients();
                    if (Client.getClients().size() > 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskEditActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Нет данных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(new TaskAdapter(dateFrom, dateTo));

Comment: Кстати, лучше не делать коллекции null. Делайте ее пустой. Так код станет чище. Например в `getItemCount` можно будет возвращать так `Math.max(task.size(), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Непонятен код в `onCreateViewHolder`. Холдер создается так

```
View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
return new TaskViewHolder(item);
```

Собственно, сам класс `TaskViewHolder` надо переписать, чтобы он наследовплся от `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` и в коструктор передавать `View`, так же передавать `View` в родительский класс

И уберите лишние холдеры с перегруженным конструктором. Оставьте только версию с `View`.

Comment: Переписал, но все равно не работает

Comment: Посмотрите тогда пример адаптера в официальной документации. Там самый простой пример адаптера.

Comment: Или ждите вечера (хотя, думаю, кто-то другой уже ответит)

Comment: А! Обновите код в вопросе. А я вам перепишу код прямо в вопросе

Comment: Выложил обновленный код

Comment: Да, вижу. Код по сути работать должен.. Хм.... А выложите еще код как вы создаете адаптер, как присваиваете его списку